# Change SSH Server Key without bothering users

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, suse

I read an article that openssh is able to "slowly" change the server key to a new one over time. A slow migration so to speak. So the user won't get those "Fingerprint has changed"-messages.
Unfortunately I can't find said article anymore. Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called Host-key rotation and it is available in openssh since version 6.8

http://blog.djm.net.au/2015/02/key-rotation-in-openssh-68.html

Comment: more info also here:
https://lwn.net/Articles/637156/